# Limit of function involving gamma and digamma function $\lim\limits_{n \to X} \frac{1-g-\psi\left(2-n\right)}{\left(1-n\right)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to X} \frac{1-g-\psi\left(2-n\right)}{\left(1-n\right)!}$$
where $X$ is a positive integer.
However, I am stuck. I tried writing the digamma function using harmonic numbers but I could not make them work as the input is negative. I also tried using asymptotic formulae (i.e. $\ln(x)$ for $\psi(x)$) but again this did not work as the argument is negative. How could I proceed?

Comment: [Here is a tester](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-khinchin-digamma%282-x%29%29%2F%281-x%29%21%2Cx%3D31). The limit for $n=47$ has [this prime factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) including all prime numbers less than $n$. For smaller prime factors, they have a higher exponent. Maybe the pattern continues?

Comment: Welcome. In general, you should show us your attempts even if they failed

Answer (score 1):

Brief answer.

I know that: $$\psi(s+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+s}\right]$$So, the expression inside the limit (the limitand? ;)) is, for integer $X>1$: $$\frac{1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{m+1-n}-\frac{1}{m}\right]}{\Gamma(2-n)}\\=(2-n)(3-n)\cdots(X-n)\frac{1-\frac{1}{X-1}+\frac{1}{X-n}+\sum_{m=1\\m\neq X-1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1-n}\right]}{\Gamma(1+X-n)}$$If $X=1$, the limit is clearly $0$ as $n\to X$. Else, let's simplify this as: $$(2-n)\cdots(X-n-1)\cdot\frac{1+X-n-\frac{X-n}{X-1}+(X-n)\sum\cdots}{\Gamma(1+X-n)}\overset{n\to X}{\longrightarrow}(-1)^X\cdot(X-2)!$$

You can play with this function [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ggmnrajve).